# Adjust labels of ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been searching the internet for the last couple of hours but could not find a solution that works for me.
I'm new to `R` and I think I miss something.

I try to use `ggplot2` to draw a simple plot for a file in `csv` format (`;`-separated).

Here is the script I wrote:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

df = read.csv2('test.csv', dec='.')
column_names = colnames(df)

# melt data so that each row is a unique id-variable combination
df = melt(df, id=c(column_names[1]))

# plot data
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df[, 1], y=value, colour=variable, shape=variable)) +
  geom_point() + # add points
  geom_line() + # add initial line to plot
  xlab('x') + # set xlabel
  ylab('y') + # set ylabel
  ggtitle('MyTitle') + # set title
  scale_x_log10(breaks=df[[column_names[1]]]) + # df[[]] accesses the atomic column))
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="right", legend.title=element_blank())
```

And some test input, `test.csv`:

```
column 1;column 2;column 3
111.12;4313.5;6678.25
222.9;9386.0;12372.5
```

So far, so good - the plot is generated.
But the legend contains entries `column.2` and `column.3`.
I know that this is due to the `make.names` when the file is opened using the `read.csv2` function.

However, I did not find out how I can modify the legend entries such that the names in the `csv` file are presented there, i.e., `column 2` and `column 3`.

I tried to extract the `colnames` before `make.names` is applied and use some `scale_*` function but I did not succeed:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

df = read.csv2('test.csv', check.names=F, dec='.')

column_names_str = colnames(df)[-1]

colnames(df) = make.names(colnames(df))
column_names = colnames(df)

# melt data so that each row is a unique id-variable combination
df = melt(df, id=c(column_names[1]))

# plot data
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df[, 1], y=value, colour=variable, shape=variable)) +
  geom_point() + # add points
  geom_line() + # add initial line to plot
  xlab('x') + # set xlabel
  ylab('y') + # set ylabel
  ggtitle('MyTitle') + # set title
  scale_x_log10(breaks=df[[column_names[1]]]) + # df[[]] accesses the atomic column))
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="right", legend.title=element_blank()) +
  scale_colour_hue(labels=column_names_str)
```

The above script changes the labels properly but splits the legend into two parts (shape and colour).
I would like to keep it as a combined legend (shape and colour) with proper labels.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use make.names. You can still melt the data frame by providing the column name as string. i.e. df = melt(df, id="column 1")

Comment: Ok, that seems to work fine. But does this approach have any drawbacks? Because I assume that there is a reason that the `read.csv2` function uses `make.names` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Here was what I did:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df[, 1], y=value, colour=variable, shape=variable)) +
geom_point() + # add points
geom_line(show.legend = TRUE) + # add initial line to plot
xlab('x') + # set xlabel
ylab('y') + # set ylabel
ggtitle('MyTitle') + # set title
scale_x_log10(breaks=df[[column_names[1]]])  # df[[]] accesses the atomic column))
#theme_minimal() +
#theme(legend.position="right", legend.title=element_blank()) +
#scale_colour_hue(labels=column_names_str)
```

and the result was:
[image: Only one legend group]

Please check if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually not. I would like the plot shown in your reply but having the red, circle-shaped line named `column 2` and the blue, triangle-shaped line named `column 3` (both without the dots after `column`).

Answer (score 0):

I refer to the answer given by @Dinh Quang Duong. As I'm not allowed to write a comment I'm posting this as answer:

To create plot labels without dots after "column" you could run the following code before creating the plot:

```
column_names_str = gsub("column.", "column ", column_names_str)
```

When reading or creating a data frame all whitespaces in columnnames will be replaced by dots automatically. So you could avoid the problem by using columnnames without whitespaces.